# SendMessage() WINAPI gets hang when used to connect to a DDE server

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, dde

I have a DDE client app which connects to the DDE server app by using `SendMessage()` WINAPI. Following the `SendMessage()` call which gets hang while requesting connection to the DDE Server. Both DDE Client app and server app are in VC++.

```
SendMessage((HWND) -1,WM_DDE_INITIATE,(WPARAM) m_hWnd,MAKELPARAM(hService,hTopic));
```

Now what `SendMessage()` is doing that it is getting hanged?  Basically it is broadcasting `WM_DDE_INITIATE` window message to all the windows in the system. The window (DDE server) for which it is intended should process the message and should reply with an acknowledgment. Once acknowledgment is received `SendMessage()` call is completed and client is connected.

In our case it is getting hang and is never returning back, as a result we have DDE Client application getting hang.

I searched on the net and found that using `SendMessage()` to broadcast is usually not recommended as it gets hang many times.

I have code for the DDE client app and DDE server app with me.

Let me know is there some way to retrieve the DDE server window handle or some way to assign a unique name to the DDE server window .

By doing this, i believe at the client end i can retrieve the window handle of DDE server from unique name (using `FindWindow()` winapi) and instead of broadcasting using `SendMessage()` I can send the message directly to DDE server using window handle.

If you feel above method of getting window handle of DDE server is not possible or not recommended, then do let me know some other method to use `SendMessage()` winapi to connect to DDE Server.

Comment: Use EnumWindows instead of FindWindow so you'll have much better odds of being able to identify the correct window.  Use Spy++ to look at the window properties, the class name tends to be good for filtering.  GetClassName().  DDE is horrible btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SendMessageTimeout instead of SendMessage so the hung apps will not hang you.

Answer (score 2):

If another process, *any process*, is sleeping in their UI thread and not processing messages, [broadcast messages will hang](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/10/529525.aspx). Yet another reason to [stop using DDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/26/1763683.aspx); it's a leftover from the days of 16-bit Windows [when broadcast messages were perfectly safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/27/432303.aspx).

Unfortunately, this is somewhat of a fundamental problem in DDE. The recommended workaround is to simply not use DDE; make use of more modern methods such as [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [DCOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or even TCP sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that what you are telling but is there some other way to connect to the DDE server using SendMessage winapi

Comment: If you know the HWND of the target window, you might be able to get away with sending a message to that particular window directly. I wouldn't recommend this approach though; the problem remains that you need to find that HWND somehow, and modern techniques such as named pipes or DCOM tend to work better anyway.

Comment: DDE is only alive for ancient legacy code from the 20th century. Why are you writing new code against it?

Comment: Dear David, I have a legacy code of DDE and i need to fix it.

Comment: So fix it by switching to a different method for communication?

Comment: "stop using DDE" is not an answer to the question! Interfacing with legacy apps is part of dev.